# R: Variable refers to values

Tags: r

I would like to refer to values saved in two variables by a key variable, f.e.

```
Variable "key": first, second, third
Variable "color": green, yellow, red
Variable "furniture": table, chair, door
```

So:

```
first > green + table
second > yellow + chair
third > red + door
```

If variable key is now "first", I would like get the values "green" from color and "table" from furniture.

Thank you!

Comment: How is your data stored? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the vector to access it by name.

```
color <- c(first="green", second="yellow", third="red")
furniture <- c(first="table", second="chair", third="door")

key <- "first"
color[key]
#  first 
#"green" 
furniture[key]
#  first 
#"table"
```